# How can I establish myself to be an "accredited investor" relative to an IPO?

Tags: canada, ipo

A US company with which I have an affiliation (I'm not an employee; I don't think the specifics of our relationship are relevant here) is preparing an IPO and there is a directed share program for a group of people that includes me. The prospectus includes this:

> The Class A common stock may be sold only to purchasers purchasing, or deemed to be purchasing, as principal that are accredited investors, as
>   defined in National Instrument 45-106 Prospectus Exemptions or subsection 73.3(1) of the Securities Act (Ontario), and are permitted clients, as defined
>   in National Instrument 31-103 Registration Requirements, Exemptions and Ongoing Registrant Obligations.

Searching for that just produces all kinds of other prospectuses. So, what's the deal? How can I be an "accredited investor"? Do I just assert something? Fill out a form? Time is of the essence here, I have a matter of days to be part of this.

Comment: I assume this is for Canada? In the US there are income and/or net worth requirements, probably a similar case for Canada.

Comment: Yes, it's for Canada, that's why I tagged it as such

Answer (score 1):

In short, they should have a form in which you will indicate your [qualifications as an accredited investor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accredited_investor#Canada).

The most common qualifications are a net worth of $1 million or $200K income for the last two years ($300K if you are married). You select the criterion under which you qualify and sign the contract when you purchase the securities.

Comment: These are the Canadian requirements?

Comment: It is an IPO. The IPO prospectus includes the directed share program so that 5% of the shares goes to the group.

Comment: I can't speak authoritatively about what they might do to verify that you are an accredited investor in Canada. In the US, it's pretty hands off. If you indicate you are, they don't bother too closely with follow-up questions.

Comment: Back in the day for IPOs, I was an accredited U.S.  investor long before I was one ;->) .  I provided  the information verbally and no one asked for proof.  I don't know if  they are more diligent with verification now.

Comment: From the footnotes of the Wikipedia article, this may be of interest, if the province is applicable: http://business.financialpost.com/personal-finance/managing-wealth/soon-you-will-be-able-to-invest-like-the-very-rich-with-all-the-rewards-and-risks

Comment: @KateGregory [This **Venture Law Corporation** page](http://venturelawcorp.com/accredited-investor-definition-canada/) specifically deals with Canada: for an individual, it seems $5M in (realisable) assets or $200k income ($300k if married) for the last two years.

Comment: Be careful, in Canada you need to pay attention to specificities of each province. Each has their own securities regulator and while they generally attempt to align their regulations to avoid regulatory arbitrage, there may be differences.